# T-sql - как определить, что текст - кириллица(русский)?

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день.

Есть текстовая переменная. Как можно определить, введен в ней текст **кириллицей** или **латиницей**? В C# это можно сделать, проверять коды каждого символа.

Спасибо

Comment: Вас устроит проверка "хотя бы один не латинский символ" ? В like можно задавать интервалы https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx `[^a-zA-Z]` даст нужный результат, можно конечно туда еще цифры и знаки препинания с пробелом добавить

Comment: Ну или как вариант, не поверите, проверять коды символов. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx

Comment: Строки типа `АБВZXC` относить к обоим классам, или ни к одному ?

Comment: если есть хоть 1 символ кирилицей, то это уже кирилица

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> если есть хоть 1 символ кириллицей, то это уже кириллица

Тогда приблизительно так:

```
declare @string nvarchar(1000) = N'Привет';

if @string like N'%[А-Яа-я]%'
    print 'cyrillic';
else
    print 'latin';
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает